# Problemas na instalação do Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, instalador

Boa tarde. Ao tentar fazer a instalação do Rails e os complementos necessários para sua instalação, me deparei com um problema. Consigo realizar a instalação e seus complemento.

Segui esse tutorial (https://gorails.com/setup/ubuntu/18.04#final-steps)

Ao testar (uso ubuntu) rails server pelo terminal, aparece a página "yay, you're on Rails". Até aí tudo bem. O problema vem depois que eu reinicio o notebook. Tudo contínua "instalado", o ruby, node, banco de dados, etc. Entretanto, quando tento acessar qualquer um deles, recebo a mensagem do terminal de como se nada estivesse instalado.

Alguém aqui já passou por algo semelhante? Obrigado.

obs: já refiz o processo e o erro persiste e ocorre da mesma forma.

obs1: Eu entendo como a pergunta está vaga, porém não encontrei solução em outros fóruns e não recebo nenhuma mensagem de erro, apenas que nada está instalando, incluindo o ruby, bundler, mysql, etc. Peço para não marcar pendente na minha publicação. Visto que isso ocorreu em uma publicação passada e não havia nada errado com minha pergunta. Grato.

Comment: Se puder postar algumas telas, ajudaria bastante. `ruby -v` e `rails -v` retornam o que?

Answer (score 0):

Todo mundo passa por algo assim quando começa a configurar o ambiente, minha primeira resposta é: `não desanima!`
As coisas que você instalou estão todas aí na sua maquina mesmo, só falta conseguir acessar o gerenciador de versão do Ruby para conseguir usar.

Acho que o que pode estar acontecendo contigo é algo que faltou na configuração do `rbenv ou do rvm`, não deve estar sendo setado na hora que você re-abre o seu terminal.
Tenta re-executar esses passos:

```
cd git clone https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc
exec $SHELL

git clone https://github.com/rbenv/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
exec $SHELL

rbenv install 2.6.3
rbenv global 2.6.3
ruby -v
```

Ou ao invés de usar o `rbenv`, usa o `rvm`: https://rvm.io/rvm/install

Answer (score 0):

Bom pelo que observei você não adiciona o source,

`source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm`

usa esse tutorial de instalação:

https://onebitcode.com/rails-linux/